# Boost (C++ Libs) Installation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, boost

I'm seeing errors when installing Boost on a clean Ubuntu 18.4 install.

```
sudo apt install libboost-all-dev
```

Gives output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dh-python gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 ibverbs-providers icu-devtools libboost-atomic-dev libboost-atomic1.65-dev libboost-atomic1.65.1 libboost-chrono-dev
  libboost-chrono1.65-dev libboost-chrono1.65.1 libboost-container-dev libboost-container1.65-dev libboost-container1.65.1 libboost-context-dev
  libboost-context1.65-dev libboost-context1.65.1 libboost-coroutine-dev libboost-coroutine1.65-dev libboost-coroutine1.65.1 libboost-date-time-dev
  libboost-date-time1.65-dev libboost-dev libboost-exception-dev libboost-exception1.65-dev libboost-fiber-dev libboost-fiber1.65-dev
  libboost-fiber1.65.1 libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.65-dev libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.65-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.65.1 libboost-graph1.65-dev libboost-graph1.65.1 libboost-iostreams-dev
  libboost-iostreams1.65-dev libboost-locale-dev libboost-locale1.65-dev libboost-log-dev libboost-log1.65-dev libboost-log1.65.1 libboost-math-dev
  libboost-math1.65-dev libboost-math1.65.1 libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-mpi-python1.65-dev libboost-mpi-python1.65.1
  libboost-mpi1.65-dev libboost-mpi1.65.1 libboost-numpy-dev libboost-numpy1.65-dev libboost-numpy1.65.1 libboost-program-options-dev
  libboost-program-options1.65-dev libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.65-dev libboost-python1.65.1 libboost-random-dev libboost-random1.65-dev
  libboost-random1.65.1 libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.65-dev libboost-regex1.65.1 libboost-serialization-dev libboost-serialization1.65-dev
  libboost-serialization1.65.1 libboost-signals-dev libboost-signals1.65-dev libboost-signals1.65.1 libboost-stacktrace-dev libboost-stacktrace1.65-dev
  libboost-stacktrace1.65.1 libboost-system-dev libboost-system1.65-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-test1.65-dev libboost-test1.65.1 libboost-thread-dev
  libboost-thread1.65-dev libboost-timer-dev libboost-timer1.65-dev libboost-timer1.65.1 libboost-tools-dev libboost-type-erasure-dev
  libboost-type-erasure1.65-dev libboost-type-erasure1.65.1 libboost-wave-dev libboost-wave1.65-dev libboost-wave1.65.1 libboost1.65-dev
  libboost1.65-tools-dev libfabric1 libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libhwloc-dev
  libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libnl-route-3-200 libnuma-dev
  libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi2 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpsm-infinipath1 libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev librdmacm1 mpi-default-bin
  mpi-default-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 openmpi-bin openmpi-common python3-dev python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3.6-dev
Suggested packages:
  libboost-doc graphviz libboost1.65-doc gccxml libmpfrc++-dev libntl-dev xsltproc docbook-xml docbook-xsl default-jdk fop libglib2.0-doc
  libgraphite2-utils libhwloc-contrib-plugins icu-doc openmpi-doc opencl-icd gfortran
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dh-python gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 ibverbs-providers icu-devtools libboost-all-dev libboost-atomic-dev libboost-atomic1.65-dev libboost-atomic1.65.1
  libboost-chrono-dev libboost-chrono1.65-dev libboost-chrono1.65.1 libboost-container-dev libboost-container1.65-dev libboost-container1.65.1
  libboost-context-dev libboost-context1.65-dev libboost-context1.65.1 libboost-coroutine-dev libboost-coroutine1.65-dev libboost-coroutine1.65.1
  libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.65-dev libboost-dev libboost-exception-dev libboost-exception1.65-dev libboost-fiber-dev
  libboost-fiber1.65-dev libboost-fiber1.65.1 libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.65-dev libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.65-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.65.1 libboost-graph1.65-dev libboost-graph1.65.1 libboost-iostreams-dev
  libboost-iostreams1.65-dev libboost-locale-dev libboost-locale1.65-dev libboost-log-dev libboost-log1.65-dev libboost-log1.65.1 libboost-math-dev
  libboost-math1.65-dev libboost-math1.65.1 libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-mpi-python1.65-dev libboost-mpi-python1.65.1
  libboost-mpi1.65-dev libboost-mpi1.65.1 libboost-numpy-dev libboost-numpy1.65-dev libboost-numpy1.65.1 libboost-program-options-dev
  libboost-program-options1.65-dev libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.65-dev libboost-python1.65.1 libboost-random-dev libboost-random1.65-dev
  libboost-random1.65.1 libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.65-dev libboost-regex1.65.1 libboost-serialization-dev libboost-serialization1.65-dev
  libboost-serialization1.65.1 libboost-signals-dev libboost-signals1.65-dev libboost-signals1.65.1 libboost-stacktrace-dev libboost-stacktrace1.65-dev
  libboost-stacktrace1.65.1 libboost-system-dev libboost-system1.65-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-test1.65-dev libboost-test1.65.1 libboost-thread-dev
  libboost-thread1.65-dev libboost-timer-dev libboost-timer1.65-dev libboost-timer1.65.1 libboost-tools-dev libboost-type-erasure-dev
  libboost-type-erasure1.65-dev libboost-type-erasure1.65.1 libboost-wave-dev libboost-wave1.65-dev libboost-wave1.65.1 libboost1.65-dev
  libboost1.65-tools-dev libfabric1 libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libhwloc-dev
  libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libnl-route-3-200 libnuma-dev
  libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi2 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpsm-infinipath1 libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev librdmacm1 mpi-default-bin
  mpi-default-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 openmpi-bin openmpi-common python3-dev python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3.6-dev
0 upgraded, 129 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,218 kB/76.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 336 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libboost1.65-dev amd64 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5                                                  
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.65.1/libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Browsing the path it mentioned (http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.65.1/), there is no amd64 version to download.

Not sure what happened here, maybe the repos and the package manager are out of sync? Either way, is there a local workaround I can apply or any way to flag this so it can be fixed elsewhere?

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` recently?  Normally this happens when you don't have the latest information about what's actually available from the repositories, and typically running `sudo apt-get update` before running your install commands to apt fixes this.

Comment: Yes, to no avail. You can see in a browser (using the link above) that the amd64 version does not exist.

Comment: Actually it does, `libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb` does exist if you look hard enough, and that's what it's erroring on.  I think there's something up with your system - 'connection failed' usually indicates that it can't establish a connection to that mirror, or that something is interrupting the connection between you and the mirror.

Comment: Interesting, I see it now, and so does the script I originally ran to identify the problem. I am still getting an error on another package, vim-runtime (can't find http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1_all.deb). Is there any reason why package availability might be so hit or miss on the official Ubuntu servers?

Comment: No, usually it indicates a mirror is being problematic, but if you are using archive.ubuntu.com then it's likely that has got newer packages recently pushed or such and the mirrors are all still syncing up.  If you consistently are getting random packages being problematic, then I would start pointing fingers at something between you and the repositories rather than the repositories as the problem.

Comment: You may be right, I should have tested that link outside of my current network. Very weird behavior but not an issue with the actual archive after all, I now suspect. Thank you for the response and happy new year.

Comment: @RexNyquist I am facing the same issue as you were. Could you please let me know how did you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @KK2491, My issue was an internal firewall the blocked certain pages or links to executables. If you ping the 'missing' downloads from another connection you will be able to verify if you are indeed seeing the same issue.